# JavaScript Integer division resulting in float, is rounding error possible?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I know that examples such as `1.005*100 / 100` produce a slightly inaccurate result (100.49999999999999) in JavaScript, and this is intrinsic to floating point design.

My question is to see whether I can produce a reliable decimal round routine without the use of string manipulation.

Where `x` is an integer, will `x / 100` (int/int=float) ever produce a visual inaccuracy? (i.e. `..000001` or `..99999`) An example proving this would be preferable.

If the answer is yes then the only way to reliably move the decimal point towards the left in JavaScript is with string manipulation (i.e. [MDN's `Math.round10`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)), and to take the modest performance hit involved.

Comment: You could check it on integers from 0 to 99 and see for yourself, since for greater numbers they are just an integer + the same fractional part as 0/100 -> 99/100. I personally did not find any visual inaccuracy.

Comment: @hdl, You are right, it is not difficult to test. :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to this test, there are no inaccuracies from division of integers by integers.

```js
var multipliers = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]
for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    multipliers.forEach(function (mul) {
        var x = i / mul
        if(x != x.toFixed(6))
            document.write('found one! ' + i + ' / ' + mul + ' = ' + x + '<br/>')
    })
}
document.write('done!')
```

Nice. This means a robust round-to-decimal routine can be created without string manipulation. :-)

Comment: Be careful with corner cases though, i.e. for large numbers with exponents greater than the 64-bit floating-point precision. Tried printing `1.0e23 / 100` and got `999999999999999900000` due to rounding error and toFixed(6) gave me `999999999999999868928.000000`

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing the reason for the difference is because `1.0e23` cannot be represented in `int` or `long` and thus has to be stored as a floating point number. At any rate I do not care about precision that far out. :-)

Comment: No, JS numbers are always 64-bit fp numbers, i.e. with 52(+1) bits of mantissa. This means integers in `[| -2^53 , 2^53 |]` can be represented using the implicit bit + the sign bit. But there is no `int` or `long` in JS (see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp )

Answer (score 1):

To precise my comments, the fractional parts remain the same only in infinite precision, which you do not have with JS IEEE-754-compliant floating-point arithmetic.

In finite precision you may not be able to represent an integer exactly in floating-point (e.g. many integers > 2^53). When dividing `x` by `100` you can actually end up with a number that is not mathematically equal to `x / 100`.

e.g. let `x = 1.0e23`
In IEEE 754 double precision, `x` rounds to `99999999999999991611392`
Then `x / 100 = 999999999999999916113.92`

But as this number is not representable in double precision it rounds to `999999999999999868928`